# Microsoft Graph add row into sharepoint excel file (The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, xlsx, worksheet

So I am trying to add a row of data into an excel file via the microsoft graph API.

I was able to successfully set up the authentication and get tokens, read the excel file, etc.

I was also able to run the request to add a new row via Microsoft's graph explorer tool and it worked there perfectly, adding the row via postman and microsoft graph api worked fine.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Example request: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/${ItemId}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/${tableId}/rows/add](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/$%7BItemId%7D/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/$%7BtableId%7D/rows/add)

This worked perfectly from postman and the graph explorer, but when I tried to do this from my localhost (react OR nodejs) it throws "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format"

Here is my code for the request

```
const accessToken = await Providers.globalProvider.getAccessToken({ scopes: ['User.Read', 'Files.ReadWrite'] })

const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

const options = {
method: "POST,
headers: headers,
body: {
        "values": [
            [
                "column1", "column2", "column3"
            ]
        ]
    }
};
    
const addResponse = await fetch(SHAREPOINT_URL, secondOptions);
```

And the error message I receive

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "invalidArgument",
            "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
            "date": "2023-02-16T12:53:56",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-request-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought I realized the only difference between the postman POST request and my react one was the body object.

The answer was converting the javascript object body to a JSON.stringify(bodyObj). Kind of assumed it would automatically do that, but there it is!

```
let bodyObj = {
    values: [
        [
            "1", "2", "3"
        ]
    ]
}

let options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj),
};
```

Comment: Great, I just wanted to suggest to use stringify. There were also missing double quotes after POST in your question

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good except the fact that you defined `const options` but in `fetch` you are passing `secondOptions` instead of `options`.

Try to use `options`

```
const addResponse = await fetch(SHAREPOINT_URL, options);
```

Comment: Good spot, I managed to put that fix in and yet I receive the same error as before, same kind of request in postman works fine, updated the post with the error.

Comment: Actually I just tried removing the body completely and sending the request and it worked, it added a new row at the bottom of the table in the excel file with empty values.

This means the request is working fine and it has something to do with the body values.